# How capture event of backspace on IoS

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to capture touch on device backspace, I'm using RawKeyBoardListener, works on Android but not IoS.

Here's a code sample, the expectation is that when the back space key is pressed, the print will be displayed on the console.

```
    RawKeyboardListener(
               onKey: (event){
                  if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace) {
                   print("event detected");
                 }
               },
               focusNode: generalFocus,
               child: TextField(
                 enableSuggestions: false,
                 autocorrect: false,
                 autofocus: true,
                 controller: wordControllerGeneral,
                 decoration: InputDecoration(
                   hintText: ' ',
                   contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                 ),

                 onChanged: (value){

                 },
               )
           )
```

Comment: I would recommend testing the ios and android `keyId` from your `event.logicalKey`. I suspect that they may be differet. In that case you can directly check the key ID (although it may not be as readible)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. When I run the application on IoS, the listener doesn't trigger any changes regardless of the key. I went to some forums, I'm not sure I understood, but it doesn't seem to work on IoS.
I fixed my problem by concatenating an invisible character at the beginning of each word.